# Need to find the pixel width and height of a letter

Tags: jquery, html, css, fonts

I have the following font set in html:

`<div id="centerLeft"><span style="font-family: "myFont", Arial; font-size: 200%;">Z</span></div>`

I need to find out the exact pixel width and height of this letter Z in order to place this letter in the correct place within the browser (slightly off to the left from the center of the browser).

My centerLeft div is:

```
#centerLeft {
  position: fixed;
  top: 47.4%;
  left: 53.5%;
  margin-top: -?px; NEED!
  margin-left: -?px; NEED!
}
```

Any thoughts on how to get it's dimensions?

Another Option!:

```
#centerLeft {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

However I do not understand how to manipulate this so it stays in it's desired location within the browser... it is not scaling correctly with the browser window (not staying in the centered to the left position). I tried changing left to something like 48% and translate(-52%... ect. but no dice.

Thanks.

Comment: Out of topic, you made a typo. Either use `#centerLeft` in CSS or change id to class in html. Right now, css won't apply to your html.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, it's fixed so it shouldn't really move when you resize the browser? Of course, the selector is wrong, you have an ID and are targeting a class, the quotes in the inline style is also wrong, but assuming those are typos, I don't see how the letter could move ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fDNgc/

Comment: "Fixed" means that it does not  follow the scroll but it still linked to the size of the browser if you work with percent. And, I just try you jsfiddle, it looks like it works or I am not sure what you want?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use jQuery **.outerHeight()** it will return outer height of an element

for getting exact value remove all padding and margin of element

Comment: But how might I then apply that value @ real time within CSS? Are you suggesting just using this as an outsidev tool then applying the dimensions?

Comment: you can dynamically  set css using jQuery

Comment: I will need to implement this and give it a try first. Thank you for your help. My first preference is to fix this within CSS if not I will try the Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by defining all position properties in your CSS :

```
#letter
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
   top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
   right: 60%;

}
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/8QTAk/